# Microbit Python Neopixel RGBW

Tags: python, bbc-microbit, neopixel

I'm trying to use an RGBW NeoPixel strip from my MicroBit and it works using CodeBlocks but I can't get access to the white pixel using MicroPython (https://python.microbit.org).  It looks like the version of the neopixel module is an old version before the 4 colour LED's were supported.  Despite a lot of Googling I'm at a loss as to whether I need to :

- import a different module
- create the strip using neopixel.NeoPixelRGBW(pin0,60) [doesn't work]
- create the strip using neopixel.NeoPixel(pin0,60,bpp=4) [doesn't work]
- give up trying to use MicroPython and look for an alternative python IDE
- Something else I've not thought of

Comment: I would try asking this on the [MicroPython forum](https://forum.micropython.org/viewforum.php?f=17). Please come back and post the answer here if you get a solution though!

Comment: Update : As of yet I've not got any usable answers on this.  I had a couple of comments that the Mu Editor is better than the standard Micro:bit Python editor but nothing on an updated NeoPixel module.  Looks like I would need to go lower level and write something myself which I don't currently have the time or knowledge to do.

Comment: It looks like that's the situation unfortunately. The ESP8266 port of MicroPython seems to have an updated NeoPixel driver but the micro:bit port doesn't - and it looks like the driver is implemented differently in the two ports so it's not just a straightforward patch. It should be possible for anyone with the relevant C and assembler skills to fix, but that's not me, sorry.